# Wordpress include php file

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I am trying to create a php website on `WordPress` for the first time.

When I create a page, it creates a permalink which is of the form `http://localhost/?p=123`. I don't know if there is a corresponding file.

[image]

I've installed `insert-php` plugin to read php code. It works fine on a static page. But how do I include another php file? I want to include `my_utilities` which contains all the back-end functions, in `login`. It has a permalink `'http://localhost/?page_id=45'`.

What to do?

`include 'http://localhost/?page_id=45'` doesn't work.

Comment: the `'http://localhost/?page_id=45'` type stuff is there for users to read pages, things you want to use as script should be uploaded to your server and their folder structure path defined in your `include` function, eg. `include('path/to/folder/my_utilities.php);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pages you define in WordPress's backend are pages mostly setup for your users to view / read. They, by default, have this URL structure of `http://localhost/?p=123` (though this can be changed, but that's a whole different lesson).

To include a script file, upload the file to your folder structure where you have your website then refer to it in your `include` statement as follows:

```
include('path/to/folder/my_script.php');
```

**EDIT**: You may also want to have a look into [WordPress Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates):

> Pages are one of WordPress's built-in Post Types. You'll probably want most of your website Pages to look about the same. Sometimes, though, you may need a specific Page, or a group of Pages, to display or behave differently. This is easily accomplished with Page Templates.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/ssiW0Mr7) is a part of my code. Should `my_utilities.php` file contain `[insert_php]` tag, `<?php` tag or none?

Comment: It worked. Thank you. It should refer to a real php file not the one with the `[insert_php]` tag.

Answer (score 5):

For exapmle your wordpress file is at

**/var/www/html/wp-content/myphpfiles/test.php**

To include the test.php file in your wordpress page you have to following.

```
[insert_php] include('wp-content/myphpfiles/test.php'); [/insert_php]
```

Thats it.